# flutter modify Inherited TextEdit OnChanged

Tags: flutter, inheritance, textfield

How can I create a class inherited of TextField widget and override the OnChanged event?

I need to reset a global timer in my app when the user is typing, and I would like to do in a custom widget and use it through the app.

something like

```
  @override 
  OnChanged() {
    resetTimer();
    if (!widget.OnChanged) {//call OnChanged if is set}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add my custom behaviour to the OnChanged, I had to "expose" the ancestors event on my custom widget. It is working, and I can keep creating my textedits without having to add the timer call to the OnChanged in every instance.

```
class CustomTextField extends TextField {
  const CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    TextEditingController? controller,
    InputDecoration decoration = const InputDecoration(),
    TextInputType? keyboardType,
    TextAlign textAlign = TextAlign.start,
    List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters,
    GestureTapCallback? onTap,
    ValueChanged<String>? onChanged,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          controller: controller,
          decoration: decoration,
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          onTap: onTap,
          onChanged: onChanged,
        );

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      decoration: widget.decoration,
      keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
      inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters,
      textAlign: widget.textAlign,
      onTap: widget.onTap,
      onChanged: _handleTextChanged,
    );
  }

  void _handleTextChanged(String value) {
    startSessionTimer(); //my call to the timer :)
    if (widget.onChanged != null) {
      widget.onChanged;
    }
  }
}
```